# How can I include Video DSI within the 1st encoded stream of data?

Tags: android, encoding, android-mediacodec

I intend to encode YUV data to H264 format on android platform. I've got it all implemented however have one small query to ask here regarding the DSI data getting returned with dequeOutputBuffer() call.

Currently, for the 1st call to dequeOutputBuffer(), I get the DSI data back. So for the 1st YUV-frame-input to the ViceoEncoder, I'm calling dequeOutputBuffer() twice to get the encoded stream. For remaining frames, I call dequeOutputBuffer() only once to get the corresponding encoded data. This approach works fine on devices running on ARM arch however on device running on x86 arch, it hangs during dequeOutputBuffer(), while encoding first YUV-frame.

So, my questions are:

1. Am I missing something w.r.t. Encoder configuration?
2. Is there a way to get back combined stream of DSI + EncodedData with
   single call to
       dequeOutputBuffer()?

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: (I'm assuming you're using "DSI" to refer to what `MediaCodec` calls CSD.)  Can you show the code you're using?  You may need to submit several buffers before any output is available.  What version of Android?  The buffer-to-buffer tests in http://bigflake.com/mediacodec#EncodeDecodeTest feed YUV data into an AVC codec as part of the Android CTS tests, so this should certainly work on Android 4.3+.

Comment: I'm targeting devices running Android 4.1+. I did refer the EncodeDecodeTest code however I intend to process one frame at a time & hence I dynamically pass frame-by-frame data to the Encoder. I've somehow solved the hang-issue observed on x86 device by 'enque-ing' the same input YUV-data twice (as I am doing the dequeOutputBuffer twice to discard DSI/CSD) for 1st frame. Still, I must comment that I find the behaviour of MediaCodec framework quite inconsistent over a broad range of devices; prime reason for this could be that CTS test-framework for MediaCodec came in from Android 4.4 onwards.

Comment: CTS tests were added to 4.3.  As you say, the behavior in 4.1/4.2 was inconsistent (and, occasionally, surprising).  The number of buffers you need to provide before the encoder starts producing data is going to vary significantly between devices and codecs -- I think it's explicitly codec-specific behavior.  The encoder is also allowed to reorder the output (forward / backward prediction).  Be sure to pass a PTS through -- it tells you the ordering, and on some codecs it's used when limiting the bit rate to the configured value.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me there about the MediaCodec-CTS tests introduction. Well I've been surprised quite a few times over last few days running my code on various devices. Now that you've mentioned MediaCodec actually is inconsistent over the range android 4.1 to 4.3, I think instead of banging my head to get to the generic code right from the start, I better crack such issues/surprises as and when I face them. Thanks for your useful comments. Again, I would like to know if it is possible to get DSI/CSD info along with the 1st encoded data?

Comment: Written up as an answer.

Comment: @Gagan.. In your question, you mention that there is a difference in behavior between ARM and x86 based devices. Are these from the same vendor? There are 2 distinct possibilities about how an encoded data may come. In one case, `CSD` / `DSI` comes as a separate buffer, whereas in another case, it might come with `IDR` frame. So you may have to check how the underlying encoder is providing the data and adapt your code.

Comment: @Ganesh, I had checked the behavior on same vendor devices and on devices from different vendors too. The results were same irrespective of the vendor, i.e. on ARM device the code worked well unlike the x86 device from the same vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video encoder is going to accept N frames before producing any output.  In some cases N will be 1, and you will see an output frame shortly after providing a single input frame.  Other codecs will want to gather up a fair bit of video data before starting to produce output.  It appears you've managed to resolve your current situation by doubling-up frames and discarding half the output, but you should be aware that different devices and different codecs will behave differently (assuming portability is a concern).

The CSD data is provided in a buffer with the `BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG` flag set.  There is no documented behavior in `MediaCodec` for if or when such buffers will appear.  (In fact, if you're using VP8, [it doesn't appear at all](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/82132/).)  For AVC, it arrives in the first buffer.  If you're not interested in the CSD data, just ignore any packet with that flag set.

Because the buffer info flags apply to the entire buffer of data, the API doesn't provide a way to return a single buffer that has both CSD and encoded-frame data in it.

Note also that the encoder is allowed to reorder output, so you might submit frames 0,1,2 and receive encoded data for 0,2,1.  The easiest way to keep track is to supply a presentation time stamp with each frame that uniquely identifies it.  Some codecs will use the PTS value to adjust the encoding quality in an attempt to meet the bit rate goal, so you need to use reasonably "real" values, not a trivial integer counter.

Comment: @fadden.. Your response is very informative. I do have one query about the buffering of frames. If we consider the standard `AOSP` distribution, `H.264` recording is supported for baseline profile only which also translates to no B-frames (Ref: http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#1133). Unless someone is encoding with POC Type 0 and Type 1 streams, I am not sure if the encoder really requires to buffer up the frames. Can you please share more information on where you found the buffering?

Comment: It may be that you can rely on this behavior on certain devices with certain codecs on certain versions of Android.  The point I'm really making is that the buffer management is internal to the codec and libstagefright, and relying on it to perform a certain way can lead to surprises.  Much of what goes on in `MediaCodec` is underspecified or undocumented and subject to change.  The only way to guarantee specific behavior across all devices is to add a CTS test that enforces it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Andy. This information is certainly very useful. Like I mentioned in one of the comments above and you too pointed it out, since CTS test are not available on android 4.1 and 4.2, I'll resolve MediaCodec on case to case basis for these versions.